# select message from two column date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

in sql server i have one table (userMessageTbl) with this struct

```
User UserMessage UserMessageDate AdminMessage AdminMessageDate
```

now i want Select `UserMessage` and `AdminMessageDate` from this table by date `DES`.

For exmple

```
User   UserMessage UserMessageDate AdminMessage AdminMessageDate

test   hi          2015-03-1       thanks       2015-10-4
test   ok          2015-08-2       car          2015-09-1
test   u           2015-10-2       book         2015-10-3
```

i want get this :

```
thanks
book
u
car
ok
hi
```

thanks for your help

Comment: please use `AdminMessage UNION UserMessage `

Comment: you only those two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; WITH MD AS
(
    SELECT UserMessage AS [Message], UserMessageDate AS [Date] FROM userMessageTbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AdminMessage AS [Message], AdminMessageDate AS [Date] FROM userMessageTbl
)
SELECT [Message], [Date] FROM
MD
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table. Then order the result.

```
select msg from
(
select UserMessage as msg, UserMessageDate as msgdate from table
union all
select AdminMessage as msg, AdminMessageDate as msgdate from table
) as dt
order by msgdate
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Cross Apply,Co-related Subquery and Order by also we can achieve this

```
  Select val from (
    select val,dval from table1
    CROSS APPLY (values ('UserMessage',UserMessage),
                 ('AdminMessage',AdminMessage))cs(col,val)
    CROSS APPLY (values ('UserMessageDate',UserMessageDate),
                 ('AdminMessageDate',AdminMessageDate))vs(dcol,dval)  )T
                 ORDER BY T.dval Desc
```